# Angular paginator does not bind properly during karma unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, pagination, karma-jasmine, paginator

I have been working on building an Angular app. It consists of a table with pagination, sorting and filtering.
Everything works fine when I run `ng serve`, but the pagination does not work when I run `ng test`.
I want to write test cases for the paginator, but `datasource.paginator.length` gives me 0 even with the datasource having the data.

Below is a screenshot where the paginator does not bind in the test run.

[Paginator does not bind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaUSt.jpg)

Below is my code snippet:

**app.component.ts**

```
  public weatherData : Array<CityWeather>;

  @ViewChild(GraphComponent) graphComponent : GraphComponent;

  /**
   * Table related variables
   */
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'city_name', 'country', 'temperature', 'feels_like', 'humidity', 'weather_description'];

  public dataSource : MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherService.getWeather(cityIds)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.weatherData = this.extractCityWeather(data);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.weatherData);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
    );
  }
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                GraphComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                BrowserModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                HttpClientModule,
                MaterialModule
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: WeatherService,
                    useClass: WeatherServiceMock
                },
                MatPaginator,
                MatSort
            ],
            schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.graphComponent = new GraphComponentMock();
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create the app', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should populate datasource', () => {
        expect(component.dataSource).not.toBeNull();
    })

    /**
    * Filtering test case
    */
    it('city filter should filter out 1 city', () => {
        component.applyFilter('cam');
        expect(component.dataSource.filteredData.length).toEqual(1);
    })

    it('city filter should not filter anything', () => {
        component.applyFilter('RANDOM_CITY_NAME_ALSKJDLASKJ');
        expect(component.dataSource.filteredData.length).toEqual(0);
    })

    it('pagination should work', () => {
        let i=1;
        while(component.dataSource.paginator.hasNextPage()) {
            i++;
            component.dataSource.paginator.nextPage();
        }
        expect(i).toEqual(4);
    })

});
```

`@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator` here `static:true` is used because if its removed I will have to mock this object in the test run. MatPaginator expects several arguments as contructor which led to another problem.

Please help me understand why pagination does not work. 
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

I changed `fixture.detectChanges();` to `fixture.autoDetectChanges();` and things started working.